# Need help compiling libqxt for Windows

Tags: windows, qt, compilation, libqxt

I have a Qt project which uses libqxt. How do I compile it for Windows?

### Edit

Ok, I compiled it, and it's installed in "C:\Qxt\", but when I try to build my project it still fails with error
..\qlocate\mainwindow.cpp:13:29: error: QxtGlobalShortcut: No such file or directory

I assume I should change the include paths of Qt Creator, but how do I do that?

Comment: Which version of QxT are you using?

Comment: Hi, I can't quite remember, this question was almost a year ago, I think I solved it eventually, but honestly, I've forgotten nearly everything about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just download it from

http://dev.libqxt.org/libqxt/wiki/user_guide

and run configure.bat

Comment: Thanks. I needed to run qtenv.bat to setup environment vars, and had to use mingw32-make instead of make, but after that it started compiling :)

Comment: Hi, there is one more problem, I ran 'mingw32-make install' to install the lib but Qt Creator still can't find the include files.

Comment: @satuon: use the qmake variable ’INCLUDE_PATH’. Don't forget to add the library itself through ’LIBS’.

Comment: Thanks, but I've decided to instead copy the directories from c:\qxt to c:\qt\<ver>\qt. It's not very pretty, but at least the project file can be the same for both Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 2):

there's a problem with the headers. Read the complete guide to fixing it here:

http://qt-project.org/wiki/LibQxt_in_QtCreator